# XSLT - What does "/." do?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XSLT, so this question may be a bit silly. Could someone please explain to me what's going on here?

I have a simple XML document (just for testing purposes) and its stylesheet.

I don't understand why `<xsl:value-of select="/.">` processes all following nodes. I tested the "/." expression in XPath and it only selects the node named `child`.

Also, if I replace the `/.` with `.` it gives the expected result (outputs only the value of node named `child`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<catalog title= "Catalog">
  catalog
  <cd price = "10">
    <title> 
      title text 
      <child>child</child>
    </title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd price = "11">
    <title>
      second title text
      <child>second child </child>
    </title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan2</artist>
    <country>USA2</country>
    <company>Columbia2</company>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

The stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" media-type="text/html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>     
        <title> <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/@title" /> </title>     
      </head>
      <body> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/cd/title"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <b>
      <xsl:value-of select="/.">
      </xsl:value-of>
    </b>
    <br/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result:

```
title text catalog title text child Bob Dylan USA Columbia 1985 second title text second child Bob Dylan2 USA2 Columbia2
second title text catalog title text child Bob Dylan USA Columbia 1985 second title text second child Bob Dylan2 USA2 Columbia2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something strange happened when you tested `/.` using XPath, as `/.` selects selects the *root node*, which is not an element. The *root element* of your XML is the one named `catalog` and is the only child of the root node `/`.

It works rather like Unix file paths (and is designed to do so), where `/` is the root of the file system, as is `/.` because `.` just selects the current node relative to the previous step.

Again, just like file paths, a *relative* XPath depends on the *context node*, so if you had used an XPath of `.` when your context node was `child` then you would have got `child`. But any path that starts with a slash is an *absolute* path and starts at the root node of the XML. A slash anywhere else is just a path separator.

So `<xsl:value-of select="/.">` is the same as `<xsl:value-of select="/">` and selects the string-value of the root node. In the [XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node) it says this

> The string-value of the root node [or any element node] is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the ... node in document order

So you get all the text in the document.

Comment: Using the term "*root element*" is confusing as there is the "*root node*" which is not an element. To avoid this confusion I always use the term "*top element*".

Comment: Then I suggest you familiarize yourself with the XML Spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root) which quite clearly refers to 'root element'. The term 'top element' is not used anywhere within any XML spec.

Comment: I too avoid the language of the XML spec. The current edition has "called the root, or document element, ...". In previous editions the first comma was absent, so it wasn't clear whether root was being used as a noun or an adjective. When used as a noun, the usage directly conflicts with the XPath 1.0 use of the term, so it's best to treat "root" as ambiguous, and speak of either the "document node" or the "outermost element".

Answer (score 1):

An xpath expression of `/.` always selects from the root (because of the starting `/`). And then you select all text from that node and below.

When you select `.` or `./`, you select from the *current* node, which is probably what you want.

Comment: This is probably a little misleading. `/.` is the same as `/` because `/` alone means the root node (i.e. the parent of your `catalog` element) and `.` means the current node (rather like Unix paths). So `<xsl:value-of select="/.">` selects the string-value of the root node, and as it says in the [XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#root-node), *"The string-value of the root node [or any element node] is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the ... node in document order"*. So you get all the text in the document.